# Cats a List of State Monads "fail fast" on <...>.sequence method?

Tags: scala, state, sequence, monads

let's say we have a list of states and we want to sequence them:

```
import cats.data.State
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._


trait MachineState
case object ContinueRunning extends MachineState
case object StopRunning extends MachineState

case class Machine(candy: Int)

val addCandy: Int => State[Machine, MachineState] = amount =>
  State[Machine, MachineState] { machine =>
    val newCandyAmount = machine.candy + amount
    if(newCandyAmount > 10)
      (machine, StopRunning)
    else
      (machine.copy(newCandyAmount), ContinueRunning)
  }


List(addCandy(1),
     addCandy(2),
     addCandy(5),
     addCandy(10),
     addCandy(20),
     addCandy(50)).sequence.run(Machine(0)).value
```

Result would be

```
(Machine(10),List(ContinueRunning, ContinueRunning, ContinueRunning, StopRunning, StopRunning, StopRunning))
```

It's obvious that 3 last steps are redundant. **Is there a way to make this sequence stop early? Here when StopRunning gets returned I would like to stop.** For example a list of Either's would fail fast and stop sequence early if needed (because it acts like a monad).

**For the record** - I do know that it is possible to simply write a tail recursion that checks each state that is being runned and if some condition is satisfied - stop the recursion. I just want to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this? The recursion solution seems like a lot of boilerplate to me, am I wrong or not?

Thank you!:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things here needed to be done.

The first is understanding what is actually happening:

- `State` takes some state value, threads in between many composed calls and in the process produces some output value as well
- in your case `Machine` is **the state** threaded between calls, while `MachineState` is the output of a single operation
- `sequence` (usually) takes a collection (here `List`) of some parametric stuff `here State[Machine, _]` and turns nesting on the left side (here: `List[State[Machine, _]]` -> `State[Machine, List[_]]`) (`_` is the gap that you'll be filling with your type)
- the result is that you'll thread state (`Machine(0)`) through all the functions, while you combine the output of each of them (`MachineState`) into list of outputs

```
// ammonite

// to better see how many times things are being run
@ {
  val addCandy: Int => State[Machine, MachineState] = amount =>
    State[Machine, MachineState] { machine =>
      val newCandyAmount = machine.candy + amount
      println("new attempt with " + machine + " and " + amount)
      if(newCandyAmount > 10)
        (machine, StopRunning)
      else
        (machine.copy(newCandyAmount), ContinueRunning)
    }
  }
addCandy: Int => State[Machine, MachineState] = ammonite.$sess.cmd24$$$Lambda$2669/1733815710@25c887ca

@ List(addCandy(1),
       addCandy(2),
       addCandy(5),
       addCandy(10),
       addCandy(20),
       addCandy(50)).sequence.run(Machine(0)).value
new attempt with Machine(0) and 1
new attempt with Machine(1) and 2
new attempt with Machine(3) and 5
new attempt with Machine(8) and 10
new attempt with Machine(8) and 20
new attempt with Machine(8) and 50
res25: (Machine, List[MachineState]) = (Machine(8), List(ContinueRunning, ContinueRunning, ContinueRunning, StopRunning, StopRunning, StopRunning))
```

In other words, what you want is circuit breaking then `.sequence` might not be what you want.

As a matter of the fact, you probably want something else - combine a list of `A => (A, B)` functions into one function which stops next computation if the result of a computation is `StopRunning` (in your code nothing tells the code what is the condition of circuit break and how it should be performed). I would suggest doing it explicitly with some other function, e.g.:

```
@ {
  List(addCandy(1),
       addCandy(2),
       addCandy(5),
       addCandy(10),
       addCandy(20),
       addCandy(50))
    .reduce { (a, b) =>
      a.flatMap {
        // flatMap and map uses MachineState
        // - the second parameter is the result after all!
        // we are pattern matching on it to decide if we want to
        // proceed with computation or stop it

        case ContinueRunning => b // runs next computation
        case StopRunning     => State.pure(StopRunning) // returns current result without modifying it
      }
    }
    .run(Machine(0))
    .value
  }
new attempt with Machine(0) and 1
new attempt with Machine(1) and 2
new attempt with Machine(3) and 5
new attempt with Machine(8) and 10
res23: (Machine, MachineState) = (Machine(8), StopRunning)
```

This will eliminate the need for running code within `addCandy` - but you cannot really get rid of code that combines states together, so this `reduce` logic will be applied on runtime n-1 times (where `n` is the size of your list) and that cannot be helped.

BTW If you take a closer look at `Either` you will find that it also computes `n` results and only then combines them so that it looks like it's circuit breaking, but in fact isn't. Sequence is combining a result of "parallel" computations but won't interrupt them if any of them failed.

Comment: That's very good analysis! I thought sequence was implemented with a recursion. Thank you very much:)

Comment: I might be recursive internaly, but it is done in a way that won't break the "parallel" properties of elements. Think about `Seq[Future[A]]` that through `Future.sequence` can be turned into `Future[Seq[A]]` - it iterates/recurs, but if some future failed it won't cancel execution of other futures. Only once all of them complete you'll get the final result with the (first) failed computation. `.sequence` preserves that semantics.

Comment: BTW When I say "parallel" I mean "simulating that (future-like) semantics", it doesn't necessarily mean that the code is run in parallel on threads on something. In case of `Validated` for instance it means that you'll run all validation before you'll try to combine them into final result - that makes it possible to combine several errors into a single error with information about all failed data. `Either` is not making use of that so it always picks first failure, but still runs all computations in `.sequence`.

Comment: Monad and Applicative behaviour:) Thank you!